# Django save image locally as well as s3

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

An image file is being uploaded from a POST REST API call and I want to do the following

- save the file locally
- also save it in an s3 bucket
- after saving the file, get the URL of the saved object

How can I do this in Django?

Answer (score 0):

1.To save the file locally, you need to have a filefield in your Model.Refer this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/) to learn about file fields.To save an user uploaded file locally,refer this [tutorial](https://data-flair.training/blogs/django-file-upload/).

2.&3.
To save it a S3 bucket, you need to create a bucket first using your IAM account credentials.Provide `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in **settings.py**.Check this [documentation](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html).
This also tells you how to get the url of the saved object.